# What target-features uses rustc by default?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

There are some `target-feature`s which can be used by adding parameter `-C target-feature=+sse,+avx` to compiler. Available features can be shown using `rustc --print target-features`. There are also some default activated features, for example, SSE on AMDx64 targets.

How can I look which features are activated by default? I cannot find this anywhere and they aren't printed when I run `cargo build --release --verbose`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit:** Matěj Laitl reached me in [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/AngelicosPhosphoros/4f8c9f08656e0812f4ed3560e53bd600#gistcomment-3782644) and told me better way to do this.
You need run command `rustc --print=cfg -C target-cpu=skylake` You can replace `skylake` with your target CPU or `native`.

##### Old version of answer:

I found that `rustc --print target-features` prints results of `llc -march=x86-64 -mcpu=x86-64 -mattr=help` (if you need other `-march`, you can use llc --version).

I gave up looking for docs and written simple script which shows which attributes enabled.

There are 3 steps in usage of script:

1. get list of features using `rustc --print target-features`
2. put it into script (it has values actual for 2020-12-06 for x86-64 target).
3. run script.

So, I got this features enabled by default at this moment:

```
feature fxsr
feature sse
feature sse2
```

With `RUSTFLAGS='-C target-cpu=native' cargo run` I got this list:

```
feature aes
feature avx
feature avx2
feature bmi2
feature fma
feature fxsr
feature lzcnt
feature popcnt
feature rdseed
feature sha
feature sse
feature sse2
feature sse3
feature sse4.1
feature sse4.2
feature ssse3
feature xsave
feature xsavec
feature xsaveopt
feature xsaves
```

Script is available as [gist](https://gist.github.com/AngelicosPhosphoros/4f8c9f08656e0812f4ed3560e53bd600).

Comment: The `--print cfg` way doesn't seem to work. On x86 darwin, it tells me BMI1 and BMI2 are enabled; but the old way disagrees, and my code performance disagrees (comparing default only vs `+bmi1,+bmi2`).

Comment: @mwlon Are you sure? For both old and new method, I don't see bmi1 and bmi2 in output. https://godbolt.org/z/qndYsGnac

Comment: Yes. I have a hypothesis that the `--print cfg` cmd gives the list of supported target features, but not the ones cargo will actually use. Observations: 1. it doesn't change when I set RUSTFLAGS, 2. I can compile with features that aren't on it, causing an "unsupported instruction" segfault.

Comment: Well, the question was about _default_ settings and `--print cfg` prints exactly that.

Answer (score 5):

I did some research and it looks like default features are saved at [TargetOption::features](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f2ea2f648e117013b0217f001088ae89e0f163ca/compiler/rustc_target/src/spec/mod.rs#L765) which is available as part of [Target::option](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f2ea2f648e117013b0217f001088ae89e0f163ca/compiler/rustc_target/src/spec/mod.rs#L677).

I'm not sure if you can ask compiler to print it somehow but you can lookup for default features via [github serach](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/search?q=%22base.features%20%3D%22) (probably it doesn't cover all the places but I believe it gives a good hint for future).

Or you can start from another end and check your architecture's spec file [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/f2ea2f648e117013b0217f001088ae89e0f163ca/compiler/rustc_target/src/spec).

P.S.
Default features for some platforms:

- [aarch64_linux_android](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f2ea2f648e117013b0217f001088ae89e0f163ca/compiler/rustc_target/src/spec/aarch64_linux_android.rs#L11)
- [x86_64_linux_android](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f2ea2f648e117013b0217f001088ae89e0f163ca/compiler/rustc_target/src/spec/x86_64_linux_android.rs#L7)
- [x86_64_linux_kernel](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f2ea2f648e117013b0217f001088ae89e0f163ca/compiler/rustc_target/src/spec/x86_64_linux_kernel.rs#L10)

Comment: Thank you! It is very useful.
I found that there is this possibility to look llc options: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f2ea2f648e117013b0217f001088ae89e0f163ca/compiler/rustc_target/src/spec/mod.rs#L759

Comment: Well, I ended with some hacky solution :)